# Assignment: need help pushing me in right direction with monitor Condition loops

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, conditional-statements, monitor

So the assignment is the following fictional story:
For Nelson Mandela's funeral, people could pay their last respects to him at a building.
Because a lot of people wanted to do this, everything needs to be planned right. The people who will have access are his ex-guards (in my code it's called 'Bewaker', pardon the Dutch), civilian ('Burger') and several 'Dignitaries'.

- Guards will have access all the time to enter the building
- Dignitaries have priority above 'Burgers' (civilians). Because of security measures no dignitaries may enter if there are civilians inside. When one or more Dignitaries are entering the queue no new 'Burgers' may enter the building and every waiting Dignitary are allowed access when the last civilian has left the building.
- Dignitaries may enter any time there are other Dignitaries inside and no waiting civilians outside.
- To prevent civilians will have a chance to pay their last respects as well, as soon as a civilian has entered the queue a maximum of 5 Dignitaries may enter the building. After which 100 civilians may enter the building and will have priority above Dignitaries.
- 'Burgers' may always enter when there are no Dignitaries waiting or inside.

I have the following code, but I keep getting stuck after a few rotations and it enters a deadlock, or it just doesn't work properly. **Edit: The problem is the following:
After a few runs the consecutiveDignitary counter doesnt reset and no new people waiting in line will enter the building because a deadlock has occured somewhere, but I don't see where. The output indicates that all civilians and all dignitaries are waiting in line, no-one can enter the building, and the consecutiveDignitary counter doesnt reset.**

Your input is greatly appreciated! (Pardon the occasional Dutch words)

```
package main;

import bezoeker.Bewaker;
import bezoeker.Burger;
import bezoeker.Dignitary;
import monitor.*;

public class Apl {

private final static int NR_OF_DIG = 25;  //DIG = hoogwaardigheidbekleder
private final static int NR_OF_CIV = 150; //CIV = burger
private final static int NR_OF_BEW = 20;  //BEW = bewaker

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MonitorAlt m = new MonitorAlt();
    //Monitor monitor = new Monitor();

    //creation of new entities
    Thread [] dig; //dignitary
    Thread [] bur; //burger
    Thread [] bew; //bewaker

    dig = new Thread[NR_OF_DIG];
    bur = new Thread[NR_OF_CIV];
    bew = new Thread[NR_OF_BEW];

    //start all the threads
    for (int i = 0 ; i < NR_OF_DIG ; i++) {
        dig[i] = new Dignitary("dig"+i, m);
        dig[i].start();
        assert (dig[i].isAlive());
    }

    for (int j = 0 ; j < NR_OF_CIV ; j++) {
        bur[j] = new Burger("bur"+j, m);
        bur[j].start();
        assert (bur[j].isAlive());
    }

    for (int k = 0 ; k < NR_OF_BEW ; k++) {
        bew[k] = new Bewaker("bew"+k, m);
        bew[k].start();
        assert (bew[k].isAlive());
    }
}
}
```

Monitor class:

```
package monitor;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;
import bezoeker.*;

public class MonitorAlt {

public Lock lock;               //locking critical sections

private Condition civilianLine; //condition denouncing the civilians waiting in the line
private Condition dignitaryLine;//condition denouncing the dignitaries waiting in the line
private Condition bothEntry;    //condition denouncing wether >...???

private int nrOfCiviliansInLine,    nrOfCiviliansInside,
            nrOfDignitariesInLine,  nrOfDignitariesInside,
            consecutiveDignitary;

private int civCounter;

private boolean dignitaryEntered;

public MonitorAlt() {
    lock            = new ReentrantLock();
    civilianLine    = lock.newCondition();
    dignitaryLine   = lock.newCondition();
    bothEntry       = lock.newCondition();

    dignitaryEntered = false;
}

public void enterBuilding(VisitorType vt) throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();

    switch (vt) {
    case BURGER:

        //check wether a civilian is allowed to go inside
        System.out.println(((Burger) Thread.currentThread()).getName() + " joined the line");
        nrOfCiviliansInLine++;
        while (burgerNotAllowed()) {
            bothEntry.await();
        }

        while (buildingFull()) {
            civilianLine.await();
        }


        //after a civilian is allowed inside, go inside
        System.out.println(((Burger) Thread.currentThread()).getName() + " entered the building.");
        nrOfCiviliansInside++;
        nrOfCiviliansInLine--;



        break;

    case BEWAKER:
        System.out.println(((Bewaker) Thread.currentThread()).getName() + " entered the building.");
        break;

    case DIGNITARY:
        System.out.println(((Dignitary) Thread.currentThread()).getName() + " joined the line");
        nrOfDignitariesInLine++;

        while (dignitaryNotAllowed()) {
            dignitaryLine.await();
        }

        if (nrOfCiviliansInLine > 0) {
            consecutiveDignitary++;
        }

        //after a dignitary is allowed inside, go inside
        System.out.println(((Dignitary) Thread.currentThread()).getName() + " entered the building.");
        nrOfDignitariesInLine--;
        nrOfDignitariesInside++;

        if (consecutiveDignitary == 5 && nrOfCiviliansInLine == 0) {
            consecutiveDignitary = 0;
        }

        civilianLine.signal();

        break;
    }


    lock.unlock();
}

public void leaveBuilding(VisitorType vt) {
    lock.lock();

    switch (vt) {
    case BURGER:
        System.out.println(((Burger) Thread.currentThread()).getName() + " left the building");
        nrOfCiviliansInside--;
        dignitaryLine.signalAll();
        print();

        break;

    case BEWAKER:
        System.out.println(((Bewaker) Thread.currentThread()).getName() + " left the building");

        break;

    case DIGNITARY:
        System.out.println(((Dignitary) Thread.currentThread()).getName() + " left the building");
        nrOfDignitariesInside--;

        if (consecutiveDignitary >= 5 && nrOfCiviliansInLine > 0 && nrOfDignitariesInside == 0) {
            civilianLine.signalAll();
        }

        dignitaryLine.signalAll();

        print();

        break;

    }

    lock.unlock();
}

public boolean dignitaryNotAllowed() {
    return (nrOfCiviliansInside > 0 || (consecutiveDignitary >= 5 && nrOfCiviliansInLine > 0));
}

public boolean burgerNotAllowed() {
    return ((consecutiveDignitary < 5 && nrOfDignitariesInside > 0) || (nrOfDignitariesInLine > 0 && nrOfCiviliansInside > 0));
}

public boolean buildingFull() {
    dignitaryEntered();
    return (dignitaryEntered || (nrOfDignitariesInside > 0 && consecutiveDignitary < 5));
}

public void dignitaryEntered() {
    if (nrOfDignitariesInside > 0) {
        dignitaryEntered = true;
    } else {
        dignitaryEntered = false;
    }
}

public void print() {
    System.out.println("------");
    System.out.println("# civ in line: \t"  + nrOfCiviliansInLine );
    System.out.println("# civ inside: \t"   + nrOfCiviliansInside );
    System.out.println("# dig in line: \t"  + nrOfDignitariesInLine );
    System.out.println("# dig inside: \t"   + nrOfDignitariesInside );
    System.out.println("# consecutive dig: \t" + consecutiveDignitary );
    System.out.println("------");
}

public void resetCivCounter() {
    civCounter = 0;
}

public void resetConsecutiveDignitary() {
    consecutiveDignitary = 0;
}
}
```

VisitorType is an Enum Class, very basic.
The classes 'Bewaker' (guard), 'Burger' (civilian) and Dignitary are all pretty similar, so here's the class Dignitary:

```
package bezoeker;

import monitor.*;

public class Dignitary extends Thread {

private Monitor monitor;
private MonitorAlt m;

public Dignitary(String name, Monitor monitor) {
    super(name);
    this.monitor = monitor;
}


public Dignitary(String name, MonitorAlt m) {
    super(name);
    this.m = m;
}


public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            justLive();
            m.enterBuilding(VisitorType.DIGNITARY);
            payLastRespects();
            m.leaveBuilding(VisitorType.DIGNITARY);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public void justLive() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Dignitary " + getName() + " just living.");
        Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 2000));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void payLastRespects() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 2000));
    assert ((Thread.currentThread()).isInterrupted());
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " paid his last respects.");
}
}
```

Any help/suggestions is welcome.

- Marvin

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually run the code and I'm not very familiar with Java thread locking. But looking over it, it looks like these lines will cause a dead lock:

```
bothEntry.await();
civilianLine.await();
dignitaryLine.await();
```

**Scenario:**

1. 5 Bewaker's enter the building.
2. 5 Bewaker's pays respects.
3. Dignitary thread activates and enters the building.
4. lock.lock() is called.
5. Dignitary cannot enter, and so calls dignitaryLine.await().
6. Bewaker thread reactivates and tries to leave the building.
7. Deadlock, dignitary is holding onto the lock, but bewaker needs the lock to alert the dignitary that they can enter.

I hope that helps. :)

**EDIT** Generally, never perform any sleeping or waiting while you are holding a lock. As for a solution, the best thing (and I believe common practice) to do with threading and locking is to only lock on the smallest unit of work possible. Rather than locking on a full method (actually two full methods), you should identify what you want to control in series, and only lock on that.

Fitting into what you have, you could setup a second lock which is used for leaving the room, this would allow people to leave even though people were waiting to enter. You would need to change your int's to AtomicInteger's for the numbers to work as expected. However I wouldn't recommend this, multiple locks tend to allow even more complicated bugs to appear, also this method doesn't respect your priority ordering requirement.

If I was going to do this, I would more accurately model the relationship between the outside world and the room. Specifically I would add a queue into which people were placed before being allowed into the room. I would split your MonitorAlt class into a Room and a Queue (probably using a java.util.PriorityQueue which would handle most of the priority work for you). People are put into the queue if the room is full, and the room pulls people from the queue when there is space available inside.

Comment: Hi Jamey, Bewakers can enter freely in to the building without any condition checking, so that should be the problem. Thanks for looking in it though.